# sorting a text file and inputting into a listbox c#

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox, leaderboard

I'm trying to make a leader board that sorts each participant by the score they get.
Each user will say whether they have one or lost then the code gives the win or loss a number.
This then gets added to a listbox and is saved in a .txt file.
My issue is i want to sort the leader board by what they've scored.
Below is all the code from the file just so you know what I'm working with

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
 public partial class BadForm : Form
 {
    public BadForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BackBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        TeaEveSel f4 = new TeaEveSel();
        f4.Show();
        // This shows the team event selection page when the button is pressed
    }

    private void HomeBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        StartForm f4 = new StartForm();
        f4.Show();
        // This shows the start up page when the button is pressed
    }

    private void TeaSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ResultsBox.Text == "Win")
        {
            ResultsBox.Text = 5.ToString(); // Whenever win is selected it changes to the number 5 so that calculations can be done
        }
        else if (ResultsBox.Text == "Lose")
        {
            ResultsBox.Text = 1.ToString(); // Whenever lose is selected it changes to the number 1 so that calculations can be done
        }
        else
        {

        }

        listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}", IndNamBox.Text, TeaNamBox.Text, EveNamBox.Text, ResultsBox.Text));
        listBox1.Items.Add("");
        //This adds the text in the combo boxes and text boxes to the list box



    }

    private void TeaTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string fpath = "G:\\IT\\unit 4\\assignment 2\\WindowsFormsApp1\\Badminton.txt";

        var SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fpath);

        foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        SaveFile.ToString();
        SaveFile.Close();
        //When this button is pressed it updates the txt file with the text in the list box

        BigServer frm2 = new BigServer();
        frm2.Show();
        frm2.Hide();
        //This opens and closes the BigServer form so that the listbox on the BigServer loads the txt file 
    }

    private void BadForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("G:\\IT\\unit 4\\assignment 2\\WindowsFormsApp1\\Badminton.txt");
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(lines);
        //This fills the listbox with the txt file so that all the information is in the file and nothing gets overwritten.
    }

 }
}
```

I know there's a lot but The context is very important. Any help would be great. If i could sort the listbox before saving to the .txt file then that would also work.

Comment: You need to parse the text number to a number before sorting.

Comment: at which point do i do this and could you show me the code for sorting

Answer (score 0):

Hy i think you need a class for that

```
    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {

        }

        public User(string yourString)
        {
            var result = yourString.Split('|').ToList();
            if (result.Count == 4)
            {
                Name = result[0];
                Team = result[1];
                Event = result[2];
                Result = int.Parse(result[3]);
            }
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Team { get; set; }
        public string Event { get; set; }
        public int Result { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name}|{Team}|{Event}|{Result}";
        }

    }
```

for example

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testList = new List<string>()
        {
            "a|b|c|5",
            "a1|b1|c1|4",
            "a2|b2|c2|3",
            "a3|b4|c5|1",
            "a5|b5|c5|7",
        };

        var users = testList.Select(m => new User(m));

        users = users.OrderBy(m => m.Result).ToList();
        //or
        //users = users.OrderByDescending(m => m.Result).ToList();

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());
        }


        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: will this sort my listbox or the text file as i don't know where to put the code with out getting errors

Comment: also how do I add this data to the list box in this sorted order

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
            //fill listbox with test data
            var temp = Enumerable.Range(1,100).Select(x => (object)string.Join(" | ", new object[] { "A","B","C",x.ToString()})).ToArray();
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(temp);  

            var sortedRows = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(new char[] {'|'}).Last())).ToArray();
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(sortedRows);
```

Comment: i can't clear the listbox as it needs to all pre-existing data as well as new information

Comment: slight issue your code just makes the list box filled with A¦B¦C¦1, A¦B¦C¦2 and so on

Comment: The code is just replacing current items with same items sorted. After you add new items you have to sort again.   I just created data to fill listbox just for testing.

Comment: so how would I adjust the code so that it inputs my text file

Comment: You code is fine.  I used your code to fill listbox and then sorted with my new code.

Comment: ok but I have used a listbox but i can't sort the data in it how do i use your code to sort my data as yours just came up with the bloody alphabet i am just trying to sort the code by the numbers at the end

Comment: That is what my code does.  I tested and it works. Are you sure code doesn't work?

Comment: no the code works it just doesn't input what i am looking for it is inputting your test. i want it to sort the data from my text file but instead it is inputting your random data can you show the code so that it will work in context.

Comment: I need to see sample of text.  I used the format from your line of code : listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}", IndNamBox.Text, TeaNamBox.Text, EveNamBox.Text, ResultsBox.Text));

Comment: dafydd | Dark-Thunder | Badminton | 5

That's the text file results also i have remove the IndNamBox.Text as was useless

Comment: I do not see why the code doesn't work.  I'm splitting on the '|' character and then parsing the last item in the split to a number and then ordering.  Just tested code again and it works.

Comment: i mean it works it just isn't producing the correct result

Comment: There must be something unusual with the data.  Maybe some lines have a different number of '|'.  If the last split item wasn't an integer there would be an exception.  Are yousure you a executing the click?  May be adding more data after the sort?